# Arbitrary conditional multivariate expectation

Tags: functions, probability-or-statistics, distributions

I am interested in finding a conditional expectation of a multivariate Normal distribution. For example, let $X$ and $Y$ denote two random variables with a joint normal distribution.

Let $X \sim N(\mu_x, \sigma_x)$, $Y\sim N(\mu_y, \sigma_y)$ and $Cov(X,Y) = \sigma^{2}_{x}$

I want to compute for example $E(X|Y)$. While I know how to get this using paper and pencil, I want to learn how one would go about computing the general solution in Mathematica.

To this end I wrote the following code:

```
Expectation[
  x \[Conditioned] y
  ,{x,y} \[Distributed] MultinormalDistribution[{Subscript[μ, x], Subscript[μ,y]}, {{Subscript[σ,x]^2,Subscript[σ,x]^2 }, {Subscript[σ,x]^2 ,Subscript[σ,x]^2+ Subscript[σ, y]^2}}]
]
```

Unfortunately, the only output I get it just what I wrote as the input. There is no solution. How can I compute the conditional expectations I want?

Comment: Welcome to Mma.SE. Start by **taking the [tour] now** and learning about [asking](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O) and what's [on-topic](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O). Always [edit] if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal working example** of code and data in **[formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX)**. By doing all this you help us to help you and likely you will inspire great answers. The site depends on participation, as you receive **give back:** vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: On a side note, you should avoid using [`Subscript`](https://wolfr.am/vxtW3QtE) while defining symbols (variables). We know they look nice, but  `Subscript[x, 1]` is not a symbol, but a composite expression where `Subscript` is an operator without built-in meaning. You expect to do $x_1=2$ but you are actually doing `Set[Subscript[x, 1], 2]` which is to assign a [`DownValues`](https://wolfr.am/vxtQt6LX) to the operator `Subscript` and not an `OwnValues` to an indexed `x` as you may intend. Read how to [properly define indexed variables here](https://wolfr.am/vxtT6JDX)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, following @rhermans advice about `Subscripts`'s is imperative.  Second, while writing $x | y$ is the mathematical way to write a conditioned statement, the function `Expectation` requires the term on the right of the modulus sign to be a "condition".  So putting all of this together we have

```
Expectation[x \[Conditioned] y == y0, 
{x, y} \[Distributed] MultinormalDistribution[{μx, μy}, {{σx^2, σx^2}, {σx^2, σx^2 + σy^2}}]]

(y0 σx^2 + μx σx^2 - μy σx^2 + μx σy^2)/(σx^2 + σy^2)
```

Using `FullSimplify` on the result gives

```
μx + ((y0 - μy) σx^2)/(σx^2 + σy^2)
```